# Is it possible to see who is using the outlook SF add in?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I want to know that is it possible to identify , who is using the Outlook to SF in Org ?

Comment: I can't confirm at the moment,  hence the comment but if you have created an Outlook configuration you could see who the assigned users are. Alternatively you can look at the logging and you should be able to see against the type of login.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried with login history but in that case i have to check login history to know that who is using outlook or who is not. And with the outlook configuration i get idea that who is assigned user but how can be i will sure that they are currently using it or not.